# Typo3 templavoila flexform - select folder from file module

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x, templavoila

I've a custom requirement to render an image gallery from a directory under "fileadmin" folder (Eg: fileadmin/images). Images are uploaded using FileZilla and it will be rendered in frontend using Templavoila FCE (a userfunc in FCE). I want to select the "images" folder in this FCE flexform.

Is this possible to select a folder from file module in Templavoila FCE? If yes, how can I pass this folder id/value to "userfunc" file?

If anybody knows the solution, please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know how this works for templavoila because I only use [Fluid template engine](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html).
But you can use stdWrap functionality to generate a [filelist](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Stdwrap/Index.html#stdwrap-filelist) from a folder.

```
10 = TEXT
10{
  filelist = fileadmin/templates/myfolder/||name||
}
```